# CSS display flex from left to right, then wrap upwards

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use display flex to display items from left to right, then wrap up to the next row like the image below:

[image]

I tried a few combinations of `flex-direction`, `justify-content` and `align-content` but can't seem to get the layout I want:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-content:end;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
.item {
  background:pink;
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  margin:10px;
}
</style>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',_=>{
    for(var c=0; c<100; c++)
      document.querySelector('body').innerHTML+='<span class="item">'+c+'</span>';
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone suggest what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `wrap-reverse`

> When flex-wrap is wrap-reverse, the cross-start and cross-end directions are swapped. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-wrap-property)</sup>

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap-reverse;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-content:end;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
.item {
  background:pink;
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  margin:10px;
}
</style>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',_=>{
    for(var c=0; c<100; c++)
      document.querySelector('body').innerHTML+='<span class="item">'+c+'</span>';
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```